# Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps'

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've tried reinstalling SQL Server 2014 and I'm still getting the following error message when trying to `import-module sqlps`. The same registry key exists, but is appended with 120. I'm able to use commands like `Invoke-SqlCmd`. Not sure what the issue is here. Any help appreciated.

- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise Version 6.1 Build 7601:Service Pack 1.
- SQL Server: SQL Server 2014 Development Edition.

In x86 Window:

```
PS H:> import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\russell_johnson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlps\sqlps.psm1:26 char:13
+     $item = Get-ItemProperty $sqlpsreg
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE...owerShell.sqlps:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

In x64 Window:

```
PS H:\> import-module sqlps
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\russell_johnson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlps\sqlps.psm1:26 char:13
+     $item = Get-ItemProperty $sqlpsreg
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound : (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...owerShell.sqlps:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'sqlps'
include unapproved verbs that might make them less  discoverable. To
find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command
again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type
Get-Verb.

PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

Comment: I e-mailed Michiel Wories who wrote the sqlps module.  His suggestion was change to: `$sqlpsreg="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120"`  However, but now I get an error: **No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 3.**  I tried registering via processes found on stackoverflow but get an error that the .dll does not exist.  I've tried uninstalling and re-installing SQL Server twice.

Comment: I have the same problem. My registry key ends with "Microsoft.SqlServer.M‌​anagement.PowerShell.sqlps110". Do you have any new on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Does it work if you change 
$sqlpsreg  to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sql

Comment: How would I change that I don't supply any arguments to the import-module sqlps?

Comment: Hmm, you could edit it but there may be an easier way to test what I suspect. Are you on a 64bit computer? Are you using x32 version of PowerShell?

Comment: Yes I'm using the x86 window but see the edits above for the error from the x64 window.

Comment: Ok, so nothing to do with x32 binary accessing x64reg. Can you edit the psm1 file and change the path to actual value then?

Comment: **After in x86:** Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120' because it does
not exist.
At C:\Users\russell_johnson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlps\sqlps.psm1:26 char:13
+     $item = Get-ItemProperty $sqlpsreg
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...rShell.sqlps120:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

Comment: **After in x64:** Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 3.
At C:\Users\russell_johnson\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlps\sqlps.psm1:71 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (SqlServerCmdletSnapin100:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Comment: Both seem to still load and I can use the sqlps commands.

Comment: Reg query that path from cmd? Are you sure it exists?

Comment: **Output of copy key from regedit:** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds \Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120
`PS H:\> $sqlpsreg="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120"
PS H:\> Get-ChildItem $sqlpsreg
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120'
because it does not exist...`

Answer (score -2):

running SQL 2014
updated script to 
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120

to run as expected